# How to Reference Object Variable in VBA Formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that gets the user input for 2 dates that acts as the lower and upper bound of a range defined as `DateRange`. I would like to find the cell address for the 2 dates, increment the cell reference by 1 row and use it to calculate the sum of all corresponding values that falls underneath the 2 dates found.

I don't have much experience with object variable manipulation. Here is the problems I am having:

1. Increment the `L_Range` and `R_Range` by 1 row
2. Using `L_Found` and `R_Found` inside a formula for sum

```vb
Sub CustomIntervals()
    'User Input
    Dim L_Bound As Date
    Dim R_Bound As Date
    'Contains Found Cell Reference for L_Bound and R_Bound
    Dim L_Found As Range
    Dim R_Found As Range
    'Defining Range that will be Searched
    Dim DateRange As Range

    Set DateRange = Range("H8", Range("H8").End(xlToRight))

    L_Bound = InputBox("Enter Lower Bound Date (mm/dd/yyyy)", "Custom Date")
    R_Bound = InputBox("Enter Upper Bound Date (mm/dd/yyyy)", "Custom Date")

    Range("H8", Range("H8").End(xlToRight)).NumberFormat = "d-mmm"

    Set L_Found = DateRange.Find(L_Bound)
    Set R_Found = DateRange.Find(R_Bound)

    Set L_Found = L_Found.Offset(1, 0)
    Set R_Found = R_Found.Offset(1, 0)

    Range("E9").Formula = "=sum(" & L_Found.Address & ":" & R_Found.Address & ")"
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E9:E15")
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably need something like `L_Found.Offset(1).formula = "=sum(" & L_Found.address & ":" & R_Found.address & ")"` The offset is the cell below L_Found.

Comment: I can confirm the .address function fixes the problem of calling the variable within the formula. However, I still have trouble incrementing the found cell. Since the cell (L_Found and R_Found) are stored as range variables, the offset command does not work. I am actually trying to increment first and reassigning the range variable before referencing it in my sum formula. When I use offset, it actually increments the value of the cell itself, not the cell address.

Comment: No, `Find` returns a `Range` object and `Offset` is one of its properties. `Range("A1").Offset(1)` is `Range("A2")`, the cell below, it does not add 1 to the value.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I don' have much experience with obj. variables. Here is what I have right now. I feel like this should work, but it isn't.                          
    L_Found = L_Found.Offset(1, 0)
    R_Found = R_Found.Offset(1, 0)                                         
    Range("E9").forumla = "=sum(" & L_Found.Address & ":" & R_Found.Address & ")"

Comment: You must always use `Set` when assigning object variables (as you have in your code above).

Comment: I have changed it to use '''SET''' but it is still giving me an error. I have updated the code above to reflect new changes.

Comment: Hey @SJR, would love your feedback when you get the chance. Thanks.

Comment: OK, which line errors and what is the error message?

Comment: From the code above, I am having trouble with this line: Range("E9") = "=sum(" & L_Found.Address & ":" & R_Found.Address & ")". The error message that I get is as follows: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: So what are the values of `L_Found.Address` and `R_Found.Address`?

Comment: I was hoping to extract the cell address of L_found and R_found and use it in the sum formula. They are defined as range objects so I am assuming I can't do it the same way as a non-object variable.

Comment: What I mean is, what are the addresses? Set a breakpoint on that line and hover over the expressions and you should see the value.

Comment: I am using L_Found.address(0,0) and R_Found.address(0,0) and it returns H9 and K9. Column H and column K will change depending on the user input but row 9 is fixed

Comment: It should be `Range("E9").formula....` but doubt that would cause an error and am rather mystified by that.

Comment: Yes, I do have range("E9").formula. Now sure why it was missing form the code above. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you try just this line `Range("E9").Formula = "=sum(H9:K9)"`?

Comment: Yes, but like I said, H9 and K9 are from the user. I need to store the date they specify, find it within a data range, offset it, and then convert it back to a form that can be referenced within the formula. I can't hard code it.

Comment: @SJR, I solved it. I misspelled .formula .... I know....

Comment: It's a bit irritating to find that you are not using code as posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a string that looks like a cell range reference. This can be generated with the Address property.

You also need to offset the range that generates that address. Use the Offset function before retrieving the Address.

```
Range("E9").forumla = _
  "=sum(" & Range(L_Found, R_Found).Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

Comment: I just tried this solution. VB Editor gives me a Run-time error 1004 - Method 'Range' of Object' _Global" Failed error.